# I would like to store a set of jquery selectors as a data structure to be lazily evaluated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know what the most reasonable way is to store a set of jquery selectors and have them be evaluated when used, not when declared.

I am currently storing my controls in an external file, and then dynamically loading the external script file after the controls have loaded.

externalfile.js

```
var repo = {
    "grid_prevpage"     : $("button[data-qtip='Previous Page']")[0],
 };
```

and I am able to use this successfully in my main script like this

mainscript.js

```
console.log(repo.grid_prevpage);
```

The issue is that all the controls do not initially exist. Because they did not exist when the file was loaded, they are undefined, even though the query would now have a result. I would like to have my data structure contain the selector instead of the results of the selector and then have the selector evaluated at the time of use.

Performance is not a concern. This application requires flexibility and readability, so concise solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Kevin B's answer, but here's a fun alternative:

Store them in closures.  It has the advantage of a mildly simpler syntax, and like Kevin's solution will not be negatively impacted by when the elements are loaded.

```
queries = {};
queries.grid_prevPage= function(){
    return $("button[data-qtip='Previous Page']");
}

console.log(queries.grid_prevPage());
```

Comment: I'd actually prefer this way, it would allow you to easily modify the way an element is selected in a central location rather than having to touch every piece of code that uses the selector.

Comment: Thank you. This accomplishes exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you too, this was a use for closures I hadn't thought of until you asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing a jquery object, store the jquery selector then evaluate it when you need it.

```
var repo = {
    "grid_prevpage" : "button[data-qtip='Previous Page']"
};
console.log($(repo.grid_prevpage));
```

Comment: Is there any way to have the stored selector return the DOM object instead of the jquery result set? This is very nearly the solution and

    console.log($(repo.grid_prevpage)[0]);

works. Ideally I'd like to keep all code free of any DOM dependency.

Comment: Without using a closure such as what @InfernalRapture suggested, no.

Comment: Well, i guess technically you could do document.querySelector(repo.grid_prevpage) instead, but i don't see how that's any better than adding [0]

Comment: @Rick As Kevin suggested, if you use my method you can add the [0] onto the return value.